# Linux bash datetime formation convertion

Tags: bash

I have this datetime 04/01/2024 16:30:00, which implies to 4th Jan 2024 16:30:00, how can I convert 04/01/2024 16:30:00 to Jan 04 2024 16:30:00 in bash.

The server is in UK, below code:

```
date --date='TZ="Europe/London" 04/01/2024 16:30:00'
```

always returned to **Mon Apr  1 16:30:00 BST 2024**, but what I want is Jan 04 16:30:00 BST 2024

Comment: If using GNU coreutils version of `date`, the code always interprets as MM/DD/YYYY. If you want it to do something different, you'll need to rearrange the string yourself. eg: `datetime_string=$(IFS=' /' read m d y time <<<"$datetime_string"; echo "$y-$m-$d $time")`

Comment: thanks, hmmm sounds there is no easy way to convert the date, will try and see

Comment: You could split the string on the slashes into an array. Then you just have to replace the month number by the month abbrivation and put the components back in the order you want to have.

Comment: The default behavior of `date`, which interprets a broken date format used by less than 5% of the world’s population, is annoying at best. But you can force Bash and `date` into obedience e.g. like this: `suffix=(th st nd rd); IFS=' :/' read day month year hours minutes seconds trash; printf "%(%e${suffix[day]:-th} %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z)T" "$(date '+%s' --date='TZ="Europe/London" '"${year}-${month}-${day}T${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}")";` It would be awesome to avoid `date` using `$EPOCHSECONDS` in Bash, but it’s just a variable, not a function that would accept an equivalent of `--date=...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case someone would like to now change date format by splitting, you can do below:

```
IFS='/' read -ra test_dt <<< "$you_input_date"
# date format for UK is dd/MM/YYYY
day="${test_dt[0]}"
month="${test_dt[1]}"
year="${test_dt[2]}"
startDtTm="$month/$day/$year"
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using transforming input yourself and then feeding to `date`, is to use `strptime` from `dateutils`.

```
strptime -i "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" "04/01/2024 16:30:00" -f "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I know we can use like a split function to split the datetime, thought there is a better and more efficient way to do it, but doesn't look like there is.

Comment: what i wanted is bash, not python

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ts='04/01/2024 16:30:00'
$ [[ $ts =~ ([0-9]*/)([0-9]*/)(.*) ]] &&
    TZ=BST date --date="TZ=\"Europe/London\" ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
Thu Jan  4 16:30:00 GMT 2024
```

Massage as you like to change `4` to `04` and `GMT` to `BST`.